# Having troubles with comparing two data frames in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, opencsv

I am a newbie and struggle with pandas data frames.

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# read the CSV into a pandas data frame (df)
df = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1], delimiter=',')

print (df)

# to open a .txt file and use sequences as a string
with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()

s = contents
s_len = len(s)
found_s_len = 0
keep_going = True
while s_len>0 and keep_going:
    AGATC = "AGATC" * s_len
    AGATC2 = "AGATC"
    if AGATC in s:
        found_a_len = s_len
        keep_going = False
    s_len=s_len -1
result0 = (AGATC2, found_a_len)

s_len = len(s)
found_s_len1 = 0
keep_going = True
while s_len>0 and keep_going:
    AATG = "AATG" * s_len
    AATG2 = "AATG"
    if AATG in s:
        found_a_len1 = s_len
        keep_going = False
    s_len=s_len -1
result1 = (AATG2, found_a_len1)

s_len = len(s)
found_s_len2 = 0
keep_going = True
while s_len>0 and keep_going:
    TATC = "TATC" * s_len
    TATC2 = "TATC"
    if TATC in s:
        found_a_len2 = s_len
        keep_going = False
    s_len=s_len -1
result2 = (TATC2, found_a_len2)

total_result = (result0, result1, result2)

d = {'AGATC': [found_a_len], AATG2: [found_a_len1], TATC2: [found_a_len2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print (df1)
```

as a 1st argument it takes a .csv that looks like:

```
name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
Alice,2,8,3
Bob,4,1,5
Charlie,3,2,5
```

and as a second argument it takes a .txt file with a sequence of DNA that looks like (it is just a line of DNA "AAGGT..." sequence:

`AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG`

The command-line argument for the code is python dna.py databases/small.csv sequences/1.txt where small.csv is the first argument and 1.txt is the second.

what I am doing is calculating the longest consecutively repeating substrings ('AGATC'  'AATG'  'TATC') out of the second argument and then see if the number of repeats matches any person in the .csv file provided in the first argument.

So far I have come the above code (sorry it is really messy and probably inefficient) and if I run the code the output would be:

```
name  AGATC  AATG  TATC
0    Alice      2     8     3
1      Bob      4     1     5
2  Charlie      3     2     5
   AGATC  AATG  TATC
0      4     1     5
```

so now I need to compare these two data frames (df and df1) and see if the is a match. If it matches, the code should print the name of the matched person. In this particular example, the match must be with "Bob" and thus the code should print "Bob". Need to use some kind of IF statements in pandas. Every time I try to run the comparison it returns errors. I suspect it is because the type of data is different in these both and I am really frustrated as I am so stuck on it... Thanks for the help!

Comment: _as a 1st argument it takes a .csv that looks like:_ That's what the **CSV** looks like? Can you provide a [mcve]? Or at least enough code/data to make it easy to test solutions?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I edited the .csv part in the initial message, so the csv looks exactly as there. The code I use -  is the code above in full and both the files taken for 2 arguments look exactly the same as well. I don't think I can attach the file here. I also edited the command line argument that executes the above code in the initial post. Thanks!

Comment: I am thinking is the trouble I am getting here is because the first 1st data frame(df) is   from the .csv file and the second data frame (df1) is not from .csv, so they are not matching... but may be I am wrong